# Where have RNA datablocks gone since 2.78b?

Tags: python, data-blocks

Between Blender 2.78a and 2.78b, the RNA datablocks have disappeared from the Outliner (or been moved somewhere I don't know), and they didn't come back since then.
What's the reason for that ?
There's no precision about it in the [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/Performance_update).

[image: RNA datablocks Blender 2.78]

Comment: Are you sure you are in the same *Outliner* mode, and under the same category?

Comment: Yes of course, in any case RNAs were everywhere in datablocks, now they're nowhere to be seen.

Answer (score 2):

I believe they were removed from the outliner display to improve the drawing speed.

I have been using the Development tools API navigator to get access to the RNA information.